# Generating function of $2^{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, functions, generating-functions

> Calculate or prove that generating function of $2^{2^n}$ could be represented as a formula.

I guess I could say that $2^{2^n}$ grows faster than $\mathrm{e}^\mathrm{e}$ or some other constant and therefore it is not representable. Am I right? If so, what is the constant?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The generating function would be $\sum 2^{2^n} x^n$.  Find its radius of convergence.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, you are right, but is there a chance that it will be represented as a formula? The radius is equal to zero.

Comment: What does it even _mean_ to be represented as a formula when we are talking of a function which is defined _nowhere_?